# What's the meaning of 1Ch in Assembly Code?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am reading [reverse engineering for beginners](http://beginners.re/RE4B-EN.pdf).
In this book, there is assembly code that I don't understand at page 15.

```
s               = dword ptr -1Ch
```

I don't understand the mean of `1Ch`.
There is no description about it on the page.

What's the meaning of this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: Are you asking about what "1Ch" alone means or about the whole line? Because the line just arises from the attempt of IDA, the program used to produce the disassembly listing, to give meaning to offsets into the stack. In this case, it didn't work out very well.

Comment: it's explained in every x86 Intel assembly book

Comment: BTW, there's chapter "2.2 Numeral systems" at page 5. Maybe you should re-read it?

Comment: And final note.. that line has nothing to do with assembly code. It's some made up pseudo code from IDA, actually rather confusing to me as an assembly coder, the rest of the disassembly looks weird too, I would rather wished to see real opcodes in such case, IMO the only good thing about that IDA output is finding `call _puts` symbol.

Comment: This is the same as saying -(1Ch). The `h` suffix in `1Ch` means to interpret 1C as hexadecimal . The `-` just negates that. In decimal the equivalent would have been -28. `DWORD PTR -1Ch` (or -28) is the same as 0xFFFFFFE4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1Ch` will be translated to `0x001C`, which is `28` in decimal. The `h` stands for hexadecimal. X86 uses two's complement for negative integers, so the hexadecimal value of `-28` equals `0xFFFFFFE4`.

Edit: 
This creates a constant `dword` named `ptr` with the value of `-28`.

Comment: How about that minus sign? Did you consider that one? (Oh, I see this is direct answer to specific question of OP)

Comment: You may notice that he also has `ptr - 28` at the end of it

Comment: In this case, "dword ptr" creates a 32 bit immediate value (masm and ml use the same syntax for 32 bit immediates). It's one operand directive, not two (dword and ptr are not separate operand directives). For example, push dword ptr 0, would push a 32 bit immediate value of zero onto the stack.